# what is the problem in creat_list2 function?

Tags: c++

I want to know what is the problem in creat_list2 function..
I have a problem in this code and as i knew it's in the creat_list2 cause the program run Successfully
  when i stop this function it ask the user to enter a numbers that will be stored in the list 1 then print them but the problem as i saw is in the second fuction that creat the second list...,I have to submit my assignment tomorrow so I wish if any body can help me to solve this problem.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
int x;
node *next;

};
struct snode{
int y;
snode *next;

};
creat_list1(node *&head, node *&tail)
{

    int num;
    cout<<"enter number\n";
    cin>>num;
    while(num!=0)
    {
        node *np=new node;
        np->x=num;
        if(head==nullptr)
            head=np;
        else
            tail->next=np;
        tail=np;
        tail->next=nullptr;

        cout<<"enter number again\n";
        cin>>num;


    }


}
creat_list2(node *&head, snode *shead, snode *stail)
{
    int sum=0;
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<head->x;i++)
            sum+=i;

        snode *np= new snode;
        np->y=sum;
        if(head==0)
            shead=np;
           else
            stail->next=np;
           stail=np;
           stail->next=nullptr;


    }
    head=head->next;


}
void print_list1 (node *head)
{
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<head->x<<"\t";
        head=head->next;
    }

}
void print_list2(snode *shead)
{
    while(shead!=nullptr)
    {
        cout<<shead->y<<"\t";
        shead=shead->next;

    }


}
main()
{
    node *head=nullptr, *tail=nullptr;
    snode *shead=nullptr, *stail=nullptr;
    creat_list1(head,tail);
    creat_list2(head,shead,stail);`enter code here`
    print_list1(head);
    print_list2(shead);


}
```

Comment: Did you look at your debugger output? Mine says: `stail was nullptr`. You can not use a nullptr to access memory.

Comment: I'm working with codeblocks editor, the program run put the second function that creat the second list didn't work..

Comment: `head=head->next` is outside the loop. `While loop ` runs infinitely. Try to put braces and maintain right indentation to detect errors. And if you are trying to find sum till then till given `n` better use formula than loop

Comment: I've never used codeblocks. I find it hard to believe that you can not do reasonable debugging with it. Put a break point at `stail->next=np;` and examine the memory.

Comment: TruthSeeker I don't understand what you mean exactly..I tried to make head=head->next; in the while loop put that didn't work..

Comment: @lakeweb that didn't work..

Comment: Your break point? Don't you get a message when the program stops? I don't know your debugger, but it should be telling you something, an error `message`.

Comment: @lakeweb i didn't tell me any thing ..!

Comment: Which compiler are you using? At that, I don't see gcc or clang on the list. You need a decent debugger to program with.

Comment: They have a decent debugger. They just need to learn to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with yours code,

1. `creat_list2(node *&head, snode *shead, snode *stail)` if u updated
   `head` like `head=head->next;` it will reflect at the `main`.
2. `shead` and `stail` are just a local pointer and any update to just a pointer like `stail=np;`will not have any changes at the `main
3. There seems to be typo `if(head==0) shead=np;` instead it should be 
   `if(shead==0) shead=np;` which is causing null pointer exception.

I tried to fix the error at `creat_list2` but functionality is still ambiguous to me,

```
void creat_list2(const node *head, node *&shead, node *&stail) //updated in argument
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < head->x; i++)
        //  sum += i;

        node *np = new node;
        np->x = sum;
        if (shead == 0) //error : head instead shead
            shead = np;
        else
            stail->next = np; 
        stail = np;
        stail->next = nullptr;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```